# GET http://localhost:8080/undefined 404 - when dynamically adding html

Tags: javascript, webpack

In my maze game app (created with vanilla JS), I dynamically remove and then add a 'user input' pop up box which allows the user to select the character they want and to enter their name. The'user input' pop up box is hardcoded in the HTML so that when the app first loads, it appears on the UI immediately.

Once the user has selected their character, entered their name, and pressed the 'start game' button, the pop-up box HTML is removed from the DOM using 'removeChild'.

Once the user has finished the maze, a 'leader board' pop up box is displayed which has a 'play again' button. When the user clicks this button, the 'leader board' pop up box is removed from the DOM and the 'user input' pop up box is displayed again.

The issue I am having is that when the 'user input' pop up box is displayed when the user clicks the 'play again' button, I am being presented with the error 'GET http://localhost:8080/undefined 404' in the console and I am unable to select a character or start another game.

I have a feeling this may do with the fact that I am using Webpack to bundle the code as when the 'play again' button is clicked, the page does not reload and as the HTML has been removed from the DOM and then added again, this is somehow causing the error?

Here is the relevant html:

```html
<div class="container">
  //THE BELOW PART OF THIS CODE IS REMOVED FROM THE DOM
  <div class="users-input animated slideInUp">
    <div class="users-name">
      <input
        class="users-name-input"
        type="text"
        name="Name"
        placeholder="Enter Name"
        required
      />
    </div>
    <div class="select-character-text">
      <p>Select Character</p>
    </div>
    <div class="character-select">
      <ion-icon class="left" name="arrow-dropleft-circle"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon class="right" name="arrow-dropright-circle"></ion-icon>
      <img class="character-img trump" src="images/trump.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="start-button-container">
      <input class="start-button" type="button" value="START" />
    </div>
  </div>
//THE ABOVE PART OF THIS CODE IS REMOVED FROM THE DOM
</div>
```

This is the relevant code in the gameView.js file:

```js
const popUpContainer = document.querySelector(".container");

export const renderUsersInput = () => {
  let html = ` <div class="users-input animated slideInUp">
        <div class="users-name">
            <input class="users-name-input" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Enter Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="select-character-text">
            <p>Select Character</p>
        </div>
        <div class="character-select">
            <ion-icon class="left" name="arrow-dropleft-circle"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon class="right" name="arrow-dropright-circle"></ion-icon>
            <img class="character-img trump" src="images/trump.png">
        </div>
        <div class="start-button-container">
            <input class="start-button" type="button" value="START">
        </div>
    </div> `;

  popUpContainer.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
};

export const removeUsersInput = () => {
  const usersInput = document.querySelector(".users-input");
  usersInput.parentElement.removeChild(usersInput);
};
```

The removeUsersInput method above is called within the main Controller on my app (index.js):

```js
const ctrlStartGame = () => {
  gameView.removeUsersInput();
};
```

This is attached to an event listener:

```js
base.elements.startButton.addEventListener("click", ctrlStartGame);
```

the renderUsersInput method is attached to this event listener:

```js
base.elements.leaderBoardContainer.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const newElements = base.getNewElements();
    if(e.target === newElements.playAgainBtn) {
        gameView.removeLeaderBoard();
        gameView.renderUsersInput();       
}
```

Comment: try hiding the popup instead of removing it

Comment: Funnily enough this was the solution I had previously but it just didn't feel very 'clean'. I guess I may have to revert to this if i'm unable to resolve this issue

Comment: i think it would be better that way...instead of dealing with the hassle of injecting views since u arent using a framework like react or angular or vue